# Question concerning Lindelöf subsets and C*-embeddings.

Tags: general-topology, compactification, lindelof-spaces

We just learned about various properties of Lindelöf subsets and theorems concernining when $Y \subset X$ is $C^{*}$-embedded in $X$. This means that every bounded continuous real-valued function on $Y$ has a continuous extension over $X$.

Is it true that every Lindelöf subset of $\beta \omega$ is $C^{*}$-embedded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is true. In fact even more is true:

A space $X$ is called weakly Lindelöf iff every open cover of $X$ has a countable subfamily whose union is dense in $X$.
It's clear that every Lindelöf space is weakly Lindelöf and every separable space is too (just pick one member from the open cover for every member of a countable dense subset of $X$).

In [this paper by Comfort, Hindman and Negrepontis](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102983300) it is shown in corollary 1.7 that every  weakly Lindelöf subspace of an $F'$-space is $C^{\ast}$-embedded in its closure.

Now, $\beta\omega$ is a normal $F$-space, which makes it an $F'$-space (check the paper for the definitions, which I will not repeat here) and being normal implies that closed subsets are $C^{\ast}$-embedded in it, so: all weakly Lindelöf subspaces (in particular all Lindelöf and separable ones) are $C^{\ast}$-embedded in it.

This is quite remarkable: note that $\mathbb{Q} \setminus \{ 0 \}$ is separable metrizable, but is *not* $C^{\ast}$-embedded in $\beta\mathbb{Q}$, (while $\mathbb{Q}$ as a subspace *is*, and is homeomorphic to it) e.g., so $\beta\omega$ being an $F$-space is quite important. Also this shows, in this case, that an intrinsic property of a subspace implies something about how it lies into a larger space ($C^{\ast}$-embedding).

Remark: under CH (the continuum hypothesis), [Woods](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102866814) showed that being weakly Lindelöf and being $C^{\ast}$-embedded are equivalent for subsets of $\beta\omega$, while later [Dow and Woods](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1985-093-03/S0002-9939-1985-0774021-5/S0002-9939-1985-0774021-5.pdf) showed that this equivalence for subsets of $\beta\omega$ was itself equivalent to CH, completing the circle.